# After the Voight-Kampff, but before the Baseline test, is there any other way to detect Replicants in 2030s?

Tags: blade-runner-series, blade-runner-2049, blade-runner

As replicants were improved, it's my understanding that the Voight-Kampff test ceased to be an effective tool. We see that by 2049 they are using the Baseline test. Any thoughts (or knowledge) on if there was anything in-between the two?

The upcoming Blade Runner RPG is set in 2037, so curious what might be the default test around that time.

Comment: The Baseline test isn't used to detect replicants at all (at least, not in the movie).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Testing of Replicants throughout the various eras has changed relatively little.**

**Nexus 1-5**
Replicants in these classes are relatively easy to detect because they're obedient, don't look very human and aren't especially bright. At some point they start getting smarter and the [Voight-Kampff test](https://bladerunner.fandom.com/wiki/Voight-Kampff_test) is introduced in order to replace [bone marrow testing](https://criticalposthumanism.net/wp-content/uploads/2020/09/Image-1.png) in those rare cases where a Replicant can't simply be spotted by a trained individual. In the original novella, there's also something called the [Boneli Test](https://bladerunner.fandom.com/wiki/Boneli_test) that may or may not be effective.

**Nexus 6**
These Replicants are smart and capable of fooling sight-testing. The VK test becomes streamlined and [mass testing becomes possible by a trained operative](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lkBsqMtfbhw). Blade Runners are also generally capable of spotting a Replicant by sight alone, through personal experience, but prefer to have VK proof before retiring them.

**Nexus 7**
Practically human Replicants in this class can still be detected by VK testing (albeit with much greater difficulty) and bone marrow testing and at autopsy.

**Nexus 8 (Legit)**
These models were placed onto a database and had a standard eye implant that made their detection simple. After the Blackout event, their detection was much harder but they would often give themselves away through their actions such as [superhuman strength](https://youtu.be/nAHKnJ2-40w?t=249), [resistance to acid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tn35Q.jpg) or heat, etc. As above, intrusive testing would also work.

**Nexus 8 (bootlegs)**
As above but minus the eye implants, these models were very hard to detect and Blade Runners largely need to rely on personal experience and intrusive testing.

**Nexus 9**
These models typically have an [eye marker](https://static.wikia.nocookie.net/bladerunner/images/0/06/Nexus-9_eye.jpg/revision/latest/scale-to-width-down/180?cb=20171031180746) and are obedient to their human owners. Baseline testing is used to identify when a Replicant is becoming unstable rather than to detect whether the individual is a Replicant. These Replicants are loyal and obedient, which means that they don't need to be detected by Blade Runner units.

---

The rogue Replicants in the RPG are legitimate Nexus 8s that are on the run after the Blackout. Blade Runners in this era use a combination of police work and refined observation to detect probable Replicants and will retire them on sight if they're certain that they're dealing with a skinjob.

> ...everybody knows the law just walked in. And means business. **As a
> walking Voight-Kampff machine, you’ve made a career out of pushing
> people’s buttons and getting to the core of who (or what) they really
> are.** Looking where you shouldn’t. Going where you’re unwelcome.
>
> <sub><sup>[*Blade Runner - The RPG* Core Rulebook](https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/1192053011/blade-runner-the-roleplaying-game) ["Inspector"](https://cdn.vox-cdn.com/uploads/chorus_asset/file/23374082/BLADE_RUNNER_CORE02_YOUR_BLADE_RUNNER4.jpg)</sup></sub>

The V-K test, though useless in detecting Nexus 9s, can still be used to detect Nexus 8s when operated by an experienced Blade Runner with plenty of time on his or her hands.

> As failure resulted in retirement, only Blade Runners were authorised
> and trained to operate their own finely- tuned V-K machine with
> uncanny precision. The advanced N-9s have made V-Ks obsolete, but as
> many N-8s are still at large with ocular implants removed, the V-K is
> our last line of defence. Over 100 cross-referenced questions are
> often required for positive identification.
>
> <sub><sup>*Blade Runner - The RPG* Core Rulebook - "RDU Gear"</sup></sub>

Comment: *"These Replicants are loyal and obedient, which means that they don't need to be detected by Blade Runner units"*  - The hubris in that statement is astounding.

Comment: *"The V-K test, though useless in detecting Nexus 9s"*. Do you mean "useless" as in "not needed, since they don't hide" or do you mean a hypothetical rogue Nexus 9 would easily pass the V-K test, if he/she so wanted?

Comment: @AndresF. - A Nexus 9 would pass the VK test with consummate ease. Rachel (an experimental Nexus 7) took hundreds of questions to come up with fairly confident answer. - > "*advanced N-9s have made V-Ks obsolete*"